# Yahoo Finance API .get_historical() not working python

Tags: python-2.7, yahoo-finance

So I recently downloaded the yahoo_finance API and its version 1.4.0. I got it a few days ago, and the .get_historical() was working fine. Now however, it doesn't. Heres what its doing:

```
import yahoo_finance as yf

apple=yf.Share('AAPL')
apple_price=apple.get_price()

print apple.get_historical('2016-02-15', '2016-04-29')
```

The error I get is:YQLResponseMalformedError: Response malformed. Is there a bug in the API or am I forgetting something?

Comment: yes there is a bug https://github.com/lukaszbanasiak/yahoo-finance/issues/128, seems the API is slowly dying http://www.financial-hacker.com/bye-yahoo-and-thank-you-for-the-fish/#more-2443

Answer (score 0):

The Yahoo Stock Price API doesn't work anymore, which a lot of modules are based on, unfortunately.

Alternatively, you could use Google's API
https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=1101&x=TPE&i=86400&p=3d&f=d,c,h,l,o,v

```
q=1101 is the stock quote
x=TPE is the exchange (List of Exchanges here: https://www.google.com/googlefinance/disclaimer/ )
i=86400 interval in seconds (86400 sec = 1 day)
p=3d data since how long ago
f= fields of data (d=date, c=close, h=high, l=low, o=open, v=volume)
```

Data would look like this:

```
EXCHANGE%3DTPE
MARKET_OPEN_MINUTE=540
MARKET_CLOSE_MINUTE=810
INTERVAL=86400
COLUMNS=DATE,CLOSE,HIGH,LOW,OPEN,VOLUME
DATA=
TIMEZONE_OFFSET=480
a1496295000,24.4,24.75,24.35,24.75,11782000
1,24.5,24.5,24.3,24.4,10747000
```

a1496295000 is the Unix timestamp of first row of data

the second row 1 is the interval offset from first row (offset 1 day)