# yahoo_finance python api `get_historical` not working

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I would like to gather historical stock prices using the yahoo_finance `get_historical` feature.  The `test` below is fine, but `test2` is printed as an empty array.  Any ideas?

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
test = (Share('AAPL').get_open())
print test
test2 = (Share('AAPL').get_historical('2017-01-30', '2017-02-15'))
print test2
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Yahoo Finance API .get_historical() not working python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075147/yahoo-finance-api-get-historical-not-working-python), [Yahoo-Finance module doesn't work anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44753963/yahoo-finance-module-doesnt-work-anymore), and [Yahoo Finance URL not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030983/yahoo-finance-url-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems that *Yahoo finance* recently [shut down `historical_data` of their API ([link](https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Yahoo-Finance-help/has-yahoo-stopped-history-data-api-service/td-p/231325))

I have found this [SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355075/has-yahoo-finance-web-service-disappeared-api-changed-down-temporarily) talking about it.

And this [Quora question](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-alternative-to-Yahoo-Finance) about what to use after *Yahoo finance*